# Term for at-a-glance-ability?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word like "readability," but more referring for how easy it is to quickly find the information you're looking for. This is in the context of UI design.

E.g.

> Having a dashboard as the homepage has more <at-a-glance-ability> than forcing the user to go to a menu.

Comment: what's wrong with good old-fashioned 'intuitive'?  "A dashboard is more intuitive than a menu."

Comment: Intuitive (at least to me) would have a meaning more like "doesn't need directions to learn." I'm trying to find a word with both meaning and form similar to readability.

Comment: What about 'accessible'?

Comment: accessible's already in use to mean supportive of assistive technologies (e.g. a screen-reader) though.

Comment: Isn’t this an attribute of ***useability***?

Comment: It definitely fits into the category of usability, but I'm looking for a more specific term.

Comment: The information is more *assimilable*, but I wouldn't say that the page has more *assimilability*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for ***navigability***.

> Having a dashboard as the homepage provides more ***navigability*** than
>   forcing the user to go to a menu.

ODO:

> **[navigability](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/navigability)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> See **[navigable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/navigable)**
>
> ‘Comments concerning the software's navigability and graphics were
>   mostly favorable.’
>
> **[navigable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/navigable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.2** Computing (of a website) easy to move around in.
>
> ‘It's not too flashy but is clearly navigable and easy to understand.’

Comment: I mean more that it's not necessary to navigate (far) more than that it's easy to. This is close enough though, that I'll accept if there's nothing better